# Rails accessing Desk.com api results in RuntimeError concerning FaradayMiddleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, runtime-error, middleware, faraday

I was pairing with a coworker, and after writing a feature using the desk.com api, everything was working fine. It was deployed to a staging server, where it too worked fine. However, when I run the code on my local dev machine, when I try to query the api (for example, request all the users on our account), I get a runtime error.

I'm using the desk ruby gem: https://github.com/chriswarren/desk

Here is a session in the rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> Desk.users
RuntimeError: missing dependency for FaradayMiddleware::Deashify: undefined method `type' for class `Hashie::Mash'
from /home/rooney/.rbenv/versions/2.1.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.1/lib/faraday/middleware.rb:20:in `new'
```

This is the error I get. I haven't been able to find any info on this error. If anyone needs more info just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Methods "type" and "id" are removed in Hashie version >= 3.4.2
You can fix by rolling back to Hashie v3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `bundle exec`? It's possible that you're using the wrong version of a gem. Try uninstalling versions of the gem other than the one you need.

Comment: I did a gem cleanup, then bundle exec rails c. It is still giving me the error.